# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'--Pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I installed `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0` following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d)

when I run these lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
```

From the terminal is ok or jupyter.

The output is:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

But from **Pycharm** is not working.

I think that I need to change the **python interpreter**, but I do not know how to change that and which one will work.

Please, your help.

Comment: Try one of these tutorials: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

Comment: What is the python version you installed in your system? Please make sure that you have installed python 3.8 or lesser version to support Tensorflow 2.2 as per this [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux). You can configure or select the installed python path through python interpreter in Pycharm by using the above mentioned [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter) by @Caridorc

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I had solved it.

Comment: @Redhwan please write the steps you used to solve your problem in an answer as a reference for future visitors

Comment: @Caridorc No steps, I just followed the links above.